# How can i store logout time in mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql

i am try to build a system where user can login into a site? I am successfully build this part. Now i am try to save login & logout time but every time i save the time i only save login time not logout time?

So, I need how to save logout time? and one more thing when i save time using my local time & database time is different how can i solve this issue?

here is my server.php code

```
<?php 
session_start();

// variable declaration
$username = "";
$email    = "";
$errors = array(); 
$_SESSION['success'] = "";



// connect to database
$db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'iotaeyjx_login', 'amitsaha1993', 'iotaeyjx_login');

// REGISTER USER
if (isset($_POST['reg_user'])) {
    // receive all input values from the form
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['username']);
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['email']);
    $password_1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password_1']);
    $password_2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password_2']);

    // form validation: ensure that the form is correctly filled
    if (empty($username)) { array_push($errors, "Username is required"); }
    if (empty($email)) { array_push($errors, "Email is required"); }
    if (empty($password_1)) { array_push($errors, "Password is required"); }

    if ($password_1 != $password_2) {
        array_push($errors, "The two passwords do not match");
    }

    // register user if there are no errors in the form
    if (count($errors) == 0) {
        $password = md5($password_1);//encrypt the password before saving in the database
        $query = "INSERT INTO users (username, email, password) 
                  VALUES('$username', '$email', '$password')";
        mysqli_query($db, $query);

        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        $_SESSION['success'] = "You are now logged in";
        header('location: index.php');
    }

}

// ... 

// LOGIN USER
if (isset($_POST['login_user'])) {
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['username']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password']);

    if (empty($username)) {
        array_push($errors, "Username is required");
    }
    if (empty($password)) {
        array_push($errors, "Password is required");
    }

    if (count($errors) == 0) {
        $password = md5($password);
        $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";


        $results = mysqli_query($db, $query);


        if (mysqli_num_rows($results) == 1) {

            $sql_2 = "INSERT INTO login_logs(username) VALUES ('" . $username . "')";
            $results2 = mysqli_query($db, $sql_2);



            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
            $_SESSION['success'] = "You are now logged in";
            header('location: index.php');
        }else {
            array_push($errors, "Wrong username/password combination");
        }
    }
}

if (isset($_POST['logout_user'])) {


            $sql_3 = "UPDATE login_logs SET logout_time = current_timestamp where username ='$username'";
           $results3 = mysqli_query($db, $sql_3);


           $_SESSION['success'] = "You are now logged out";
           header('location: index.php');

}
```

?>

here is my index.php code

```
<?php 



session_start(); 

if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    $_SESSION['msg'] = "You must log in first";
    header('location: login.php');
}

if (isset($_GET['logout'])) {
    session_destroy();
    unset($_SESSION['username']);
    header("location: login.php");
}
```

?>

```
    <!-- notification message -->
    <?php if (isset($_SESSION['success'])) : ?>
        <div class="error success" >
            <h3>
                <?php 
                    echo $_SESSION['success']; 
                    unset($_SESSION['success']);
                ?>
            </h3>
        </div>
    <?php endif ?>

    <!-- logged in user information -->
    <?php  if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) : ?>
        <p>Welcome <strong><?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?></strong></p>

        <br>
        <p> <a href="index.php?logout='1'" style="color: red;">Are you Ready to go HOME? Click Here!!</a> </p>
    <?php endif ?>


</div>
```

Thank you all.

Comment: A side note: `md5(...)`  is NOT an encryption algorithm as your comment suggest. Also it is NOT a good hashing algorithm, so it should not be used in user account systems. There are many tutorials online that explain why and what algorithms to use.

Comment: Apart from that: you really should learn about the benefits of using "prepared statements" in combination with "parameter binding".

Comment: You have the code in server.php, just move it into index.php..

Comment: Your code also suffers from SQL injection vulnerabilities.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion @arkascha

Comment: what is the best way to do that ?? any sample project?

Comment: There is nothing obviously wrong with your code (apart from what I mentioned above). So if things do not work as expected you will have to start debugging to find out what is actually going on. Two things you usually start with: 1. monitor your http servers error log file, that is where php errors are logged to and 2. start using a debugger to be able to step through the code whilst it is processed.

Comment: "A sample project"? I have given you the terms in my comments, you will easily find good examples if you try.

Comment: really thank you @arkascha but i am a beginner in PHP. i am just trying this things. Can you please specify now where i can edit my code ??

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use manual escaping and string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Accidentally unescaped data is a serious risk. Using bound parameters is less verbose and easier to review to check you’re doing it properly.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and **never store passwords as plain-text** or a weak hash like **SHA1 or MD5**.

Comment: Remember, very few users will explicitly logout of your site. Most will just let the session expire. Tracking "last used" time is a lot easier than tracking "logged out".

Answer (score 0):

The best way to resolve the option of storing login, logout time in DB is to use `timestamp` as the *field* (Which is a standard since it gets the time in GMT)

Using php `now()` function we can insert the date value.

To get `timestamp` of some other date in PHP,

```
$timestamp = date('Y-m-d G:i:s', mktime(0, 0, 0, 7, 1, 2000));
```

Comment: can you please edit my code where i can do this? i can't get your point